# Why am I seeing two different point types in Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highcharts synchronization example working fine on JS Fiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/profnimrod/5vcc6z40/18/
```

However, when I integrate this into a larger app I'm seeing something weird.  When I do some debugging on the JS Fiddle version I see that in each point in the:

```
chart.series[0].points
```

array has the following fields:

[image]

However, when I view the same array in my larger app I see the following:

[image]

I am, as far as I can tell, utilizing the current (6.0.3) version of Highcharts in both cases.  What's going on?

Comment: What's the question exactly ?

Comment: Why am I seeing two very different point classes with very similar code?  I can't see anything obvious with the chart options.

Comment: Another way to put it - why does the second graphic not include all properties a point is support to have according to https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point

Answer (score 0):

The difference in my chart options was that in my larger app I had the 'boost' option enabled.  This is used to handle charts containing many 1000s of points.  It seems that it uses a different 'point' class when in boost mode which explains the issue I observed above.